# Timestamp of generated bitmap - Android

Tags: android, android-image

I have an app where I have downloaded an image file from the web and I save this file in external storage.

Later, to add this image to the media store, I call:

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                fullPath, "IMG_"+System.currentTimeMillis(),null);
```

However,  my picture always adds to the end of the gallery - it thinks that the picture was taken in 1970.  How do I change this information?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe you can write a specific date/timestamp to the img by way of [ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html#TAG_DATETIME) `setAttribute()`

Comment: I tried this but I get "Can't write back - didn't read all" in the logs :(

Comment: got it working thanks! I was saving my images as png's originally!

Comment: Awesome, so just to make sure, did you converted them to jpeg's and then used the `ExifInterface`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked using JPEGS (not PNG!) with ExifInterface

Comment: I'm using your same method and i can't change the date, can you post me the code that worked please??