# Bitmap image saved in wrong order Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I have ap app that saves a screenshot to the gallery. I use the following method to save the screenshot:

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),bitmap, timeStamp + ".jpg",timeStamp.toString());
```

The screenshot is saved correctly in the gallery but in the wrong order (their date is 01/01/1970 01:00:00 so they start from the last spot in the gallery).
How can I fix this? Should I change method or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please explain what you mean exactly with `the wrong order`. And what do you mean exactly with `it's date is wrong`? What should toString() in `timeStamp.toString()` do when timeStamp is already a String?

Comment: What is the contents/valie of timeStamp before use? Tell what the file name becomes of the image.

Comment: Edited my question, the date assigned to the image is wrong so they get placed last in the gallery, timeStamp.toString is the method that should give the date even if i'm not that sure now :\

Comment: file name is: 20141024_125115.jpg which is the correct date time

Comment: Please explain the last parameter `timeStamp.toString()`. For what is it used?

Comment: `saves a screenshot to the gallery.` The gallery is not a storage place as the Gallery is only an app which shows images from all kind of places on your device. Where is your image saved? The return value of insertImage() will tell you. Do the other files in the used directory have the same file name format and extension?

Comment: Screenshots in Android are mostly saved as .png in a different directory as the .jpg's from camera apps. What are you doing to save them to the right directory? And why use .jpg? Will the media store reallyy save your Bitmap as a jpeg only while you supply .jpg in the filename?

Comment: My Screenshots are saved in the Camera roll. The directory where they're saved depends if the device has or not an External Storage (i'm using a Galaxy S2 with external storage and a Moto G with no External Storage). The file gets saved as Jpeg by the method, my + ".jpg" means nothing, it's just to know the file extension inside the file name

Comment: `the Camera roll`. What is that? Please give an absolute path. `an External Storage`. All devices have internal and external storage. And in many devices you can put a micro SD card. That is called removable storage. Please just supply the real paths.

Comment: This is the path for the Moto G: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/filename.jpg
It should be different for the Galaxy S

Comment: I think I found a solution but I can't understand how to implement it, it uses ExifInterface setAttribute()
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180934/timestamp-of-generated-bitmap-android

Comment: If you cannot solve the issue i suggest to save the bitmap as .png in the Pictures/Screenshots directory.  Try Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)

Comment: As the bitmap does not have an exif and the media store is not adding an exif info to the jpg and the Gallery app expects exif info in every .jpg in the DCIM/Camera dir you will get 1970 date if there is no exif info. I suppose the filetime for the file is ok and that the Gallery app does not look at filetime when no exif info available. Your link unfortunately does not tell how to add an exif info. So you have to find that out or indeed save as .png in Pictures directory as .png have no exif info. Why do you want to save a screenshot in the Camera dir? Bad idea i think. No user will want it.